# jupyter nbconvert doesn't work in the environment created by snakemake --use-conda

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, snakemake, nbconvert

I've stuck on this problem for several days.

I created environment envs/jupyter.yaml as followed

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - libgcc-ng=12.2.0
  - libblas=3.9.0
  - liblapack=3.9.0
  - notebook=6.5.2
  - r-base=4.2.1
  - r-tidyverse=1.3.2
  - bioconductor-complexheatmap=2.14.0
  - bioconductor-biostrings=2.66.0
  - r-irkernel=1.3.1
  - jupyter_contrib_nbextensions=0.7.0
  - biopython=1.74
  - scipy=1.10.0
```

the snakefile rules looks like

```
rules stat:
    conda: 'envs/jupyter.yaml'
    notebook: rules.notebook.output.stat
```

When I run "snakemake --use-conda", the error

```
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/dd29012628c49c75d6a5c31f75898e03
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/.snakemake/conda/dd29012628c49c75d6a5c31f75898e03/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 6, in <module>
    from nbconvert.nbconvertapp import main
  File "/share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/.snakemake/conda/dd29012628c49c75d6a5c31f75898e03/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 185, in <module>
    class NbConvertApp(JupyterApp):
  File "/share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/.snakemake/conda/dd29012628c49c75d6a5c31f75898e03/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 278, in NbConvertApp
    formats=get_export_names()
  File "/share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/.snakemake/conda/dd29012628c49c75d6a5c31f75898e03/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 137, in get_export_names
    exporters = sorted(e.name for e in entry_points(group="nbconvert.exporters"))
TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file /share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/Snakefile, line 310:
Command 'source /share/home/sibyl/miniconda3/envs/sars2/bin/activate '/share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/.snakemake/conda/dd29012628c49c75d6a5c31f75898e03'; set -euo pipefail;  jupyter-nbconvert --log-level ERROR --execute --output /share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/test/output/0log/upstream_stat/test.r.ipynb --to notebook --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 /share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/.snakemake/scripts/tmpcnlnf1wn.upstream_stat.r.ipynb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/share/home/sibyl/bak/sars2_surveillance/Snakefile", line 310, in __rule_upstream_stat
  File "/share/home/sibyl/miniconda3/envs/sars2/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
```

my nbconvert version

```
  - nbconvert=7.2.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-core=7.2.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-pandoc=7.2.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
```

When I went into the virtual environment dd29012628c49c75d6a5c31f75898e03, the command 'jupyter nbconvert' return TypeError like before, even after I reinstalled nbconvert. I also tried to install nbconvert v7.1.0. Same error.

Everything worked perfectly several days ago.Really need help! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why coinstalling R and Python in the same environment? That is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue related to `markdown`, see [this thread](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19804) for discussion.

One solution is to add an explicit `markdown` version to the `yaml`:

```yaml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - markdown==3.3.4
# the rest of dependencies listed
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me.But still thanks.

Comment: The [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19804) you provided here mentioned the error is from /markdown/util.py, not nbconvert. I did try to set nbconvert version to 7.2.7/7.1.0 and nothing changed.